# A feeling of there is "something more to it"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Sometimes after encountering certain events or incidents, we may consequentially sense a kind of uncanny feeling. It often feels like there is "something more to it" or "certain enlightenment or revelation" ahead for us to find out. The feeling is generally positive, something that we are looking forward to know "what's next".

What do we name/describe this kind of feeling as?

Comment: suspicion, inkling?

Comment: *[Presque vu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presque_vu)* may be one small instance of such a feeling; that is, a hyponym of what you seek.

Comment: This resembles the feeling that [Lewis Thomas](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/punctuation.html) says the semicolon engenders in him:

Comment: "I have grown fond of semicolons in recent years. The semicolon tells you that there is still some question about the preceding full sentence; something needs to be added; it reminds you sometimes of the Greek usage. It is almost always a greater pleasure to come across a semicolon than a period.

Comment: "The period tells you that that is that; if you didn't get all the meaning you wanted or expected, anyway you got all the writer intended to parcel out and now you have to move along. But with a semicolon there you get a pleasant little feeling of expectancy; there is more to come; to read on; it will get clearer."

Comment: Foreshadowing as a narrative device serves to hint at the future events, and if done well leaves the reader/viewer with a vague sense of impending action, or if done badly it leaves them saying, "oh he just coughed, he's going to die", or "the railing is loose, it's probably going to fail at just the wrong moment later on."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The feeling is generally positive, something that we are looking
>   forward to know "what's next".

I suggest [*anticipation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticipation_(emotion)).

Comment: +1 You, sir, have hit it.  *Anticipation* is excellent, and better than the rest because of its largely positive connotation.

Comment: Odd how it was so easy to come up with foreboding words that suggest imminent doom, but far more challenging to find something optimistic.  Not something I would have anticipated.

Answer (score 3):

*[Suspicion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suspicion)* comes to mind, though a little vague, and it has connotations of mistrust:

> **5.** imagination of anything to be the case or to be likely; a vague notion of something.

*[Hunch](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hunch)* is the best I can think of, as it describes an intuitive idea of circumstances which is not based on proof.

As to being a vague but positive "what's next" feeling, such as you describe, I'm not sure there is a concise term for it.

Answer (score 3):

***Uncanny*** isn't bad.

***Eerie*** or ***haunting*** might work, particularly if the "something more to it" is inclined to be a negative thing.  (I've used ***spooky*** to describe this feeling on occasion, but that's not really a very accurate word, unless one is focused on the unexplainable or supernatural).

***Ominous*** and ***premonition*** usually connote some bad feelings about what is to come as well.

***Hunch*** is more neutral, defined as *a feeling that something is true or will happen, although no definite facts about it are known*.

Some possible idioms:

***Sixth sense***; ***sneaking suspicion***; ***gut feeling***.

Comment: I think "premonition" or "hunch" would fit what the OP wants.